# Managing access control for sub-folders within a Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, office-365

Organization wants to move a network share to SharePoint Online (OneDrive). Needs a bit of granularity WRT permissions.

**Contrived example:**

```
Blueprint Site
 -Documents
  --Project A
    --Drawings
    --Models
    --Bills of Lading
  --Project B
    --Drawings
    --Models
    --Bills of Lading
```

**User List:**

- VP Engineering - needs read/write access to everything
- Purchasing Mgr - needs read access to Documents/__/Drawings
- Logistics Rep - needs read/write access to Documents/__/Bills of Lading

I've poked around in the advanced permissions section online. I guess my questions are as follows:

1. Does SP support access restrictions with this much granularity?
2. If yes, how would one go about setting it up? Do I need to touch each and every directory/file?
3. Is there a script/batch file way of setting a truckload of permissions?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft enterprise support was able to sort this out:

1. Open your SP site's document library
2. Navigate to the folder you want to change permissions for
3. Make sure you are in "Classic Sharepoint" mode (look in the far bottom left corner)
4. Click LIBRARY in the top ribbon
5. Click LIBRARY SETTINGS
6. Select *Permissions for this document library*
7. De-sync permissions
8. Grant permissions on an as-user
   basis as needed